# Mann-Kendall Trend Test

Tags: signal-analysis, python, statistics, covariance, normalization

I'm using the pyMannKendall package in Python to detect the presence of slope of any given waveform. More details of the package here:
https://github.com/mmhs013/pyMannKendall

I'm not exactly able to understand what do some of its output parameters listed below signify:

*z: normalized test statistics*

*Tau: Kendall Tau*

*s: Mann-Kendal's score*

*var_s: Variance S*

*slope: Theil-Sen estimator/slope*

*intercept: intercept of Kendall-Theil Robust Line*

**Can anyone please explain what do these represent?**

**Also, what are the inner workings of the Mann-Kendall Test? Does it just approximate the signal as linear and then estimate the slope?**